# To disable button or to not disable button?

Tags: forms, buttons, disable

Simple question, should a button be disabled if the form is not finished, i.e. still missing some input of mandatory fields? 
Why/Why not?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're working on. You can have multiple approaches here such as

1. It can be disabled until completion if you're instantly validating every form field and also showing him the validation status of each field instantly.
2. Show a message beside the disabled button that says "form can be submitted only upon completion" or similar.

Comment: what about a login or signup form?